# UPDATE statement and WITH clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update my table using `WITH` clause. 
I was trying:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET myfield = (
   WITH sub AS (SELECT 18) 
   SELECT CASE WHEN (sub = 18) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)
```

and

```
WITH sub AS (SELECT 18)
UPDATE mytable 
SET myfield = ( 
   SELECT CASE WHEN (sub = 18) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)
```

But it does not work. Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

your `sub` is recordset, not column. This one will work:

```
with sub(col) as (select 18)
update mytable set
   myfield = (select case when col = 18 then 100 else 0 end from sub)
```

But it'll update all rows in `mytable` with 100. Don't know what do you want to do with your query, so can't be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET myfield = (
   WITH sub AS (SELECT 18 AS field) 
   SELECT CASE WHEN (field = 18) THEN 100 ELSE 0 END
   FROM sub)
```

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause defines a "common table expression", and is treated as a table in subsequent queries. So, you still need to reference the common table expression name in the subsequent query just as you would a table, and I find it more clear to prefix the CTE name with cte_ just to make it clear in a complex expression what the source of the data is.

```
update mytable 
set    myfield = (
         with cte_sub as
           (select 18 as field) 
         select case field
                  when 18 then 100
                  else 0
                end
         from cte_sub)
```